# Javascript slideshow is getting stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I am making a slideshow in Javascript and it is getting stuck on the second image. If you need more info let me know and ill post it. I really need this fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/QURLC/1/

Javascript:

```
function slideShow() {
      var showing = $('#slideshow a');
      var next = showing.next().length ? showing.next() : showing.parent().children(':first');
      var timer;

    showing.fadeOut(500, function() { next.fadeIn(200).addClass('show'); }).removeClass('show');

    setTimeout(slideShow, 3500);  
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    slideShow();
});
```

Comment: +1 for including your jsfiddle. :)

Comment: Hey you have forgot to include jquery in your jsfiddle, so it doesn't work :)

Comment: =)) all your image is show and fade at the same time, you called your function on all your <a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is updated and working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QURLC/4/)

```
function slideShow() {

      var showing = $('#slideshow a.show');
      var next = showing.next().length ? showing.next() : showing.parent().children(':first');
      var timer;

      showing.fadeOut(500, function() { next.fadeIn(200).addClass('show'); }).removeClass('show');

      setTimeout(slideShow, 3500);

    }
```

Comment: Now is it easy to add a pause when hovering, or too complex?

Comment: @rlemon I've just edited his code to work, there can be many things to optimize.

Comment: @GarrettJohnson Just save setTimeout in variable and clearTimeout on hover and again add timeout when hover out. And accept my answer if you are satisfied with it.